# JQuery .load() does not load html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

help me please to figure out what I'm missing.

That's my html named "test.html"

```
<div id="div-test">
lalalalaal
    <ul>
        <li>Hi</li>
        <li>By</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And that's another html file in the same directory, that contains this:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#result").load("test.html");
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't load anything.

however, this works fine:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#result").html("i see this text");
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can't run ajax locally, it will work on the server, or you can use script tag injection

Comment: What does your browser's JavaScript error console tell you?

Comment: Console, does not show any errors.... I'm trying to follow Benjamin's answer and make some function on my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i need to load data regularly i just create a function to load dynamically so i can either call it when i need, or when the page is done loading

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            function loadContent(divName,pageURL) {
                $("#" + divName).load(pageURL);
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                loadContent('createArea','create_login.php');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="float:left;width:500px;min-width:500px;min-height:200px;">
            <div id="createArea" name="createArea"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As noted below, this will not execute locally unless you're running a WAMP server. Also the paths to the files you are loading may need to be relative if they are not residing in the same directory as the page with this code.

Comment: as noted by others, this will not execute locally unless you have a WAMP/Web server or something equivalent, and the relative path may need to be checked as kleinohad shows.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome or IE9, try monitoring XHR network calls to see what 
*really* happens. On chrome, you monitor XHR calls by

1. Clicking on F12
2. Click network button
3. Click on XHR label at the very bottom of the console.
4. With the console open, exec the page whose code doesn't work and check if there's an actual data exchange.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#result").load("/test.html"); // add "/"
});
</script>
```